# Facebook mobile version of comments is too narrow on UIWebView on iPad

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad

I am trying to add Facebook comments box to the application using HTML5 code. The code is generated by [FB tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/).
The view is regular iOS UIWebView.

The problem is that comments box is too narrow for the iPad. When clicking "Login" button, the next login page comes up with the normal width (100% of the screen).
How can I force mobile version of the comments to be stretched to the width of the view?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed -- the question is perfectly clear. I ran into a similar situation and came across another question; posted an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984389/facebook-comments-plugin-displays-mobile-width-on-ipad/