# Facebook Comments Plugin Displays Mobile Width on iPad

Tags: facebook, width, facebook-comments

As the title says. Here is the URL if you have an iPad - How can I remove the responsive width of the Comments Plugin for iPads? (bottom of page) http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/aptitudetests_numerical.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this too. I've worked around it by manually adding the `data-mobile` attribute set to `false` if I detect this is on an iPad:

```
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/\biPad\b/)) {
        document.querySelector('div.fb-comments')
            .setAttribute('data-mobile', 'false');
    }
</script>
```

This could be improved to handle other tablets as well, but the best way to do that depends on how Facebook auto-detects "mobile", which I'm not sure of. Perhaps based on display width, perhaps based on the presence of touch event handlers, or perhaps indeed by user-agent on the server-side.

Comment: This is good. I've added the above script to the HTML but it does not work? IS there anything else I need to add? If you view source, I've added it with the Facebook script tag at the bottom - http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/aptitudetests_numerical.htm

Comment: You need to be setting the `mobile` attribute on the actual Facebook comments element. You're using FBXML, so it's the `<fb:comments>` element. I don't know how to query for that, but perhaps someone else does. You could try switching to the HTML5 code -- that looks like `<div class="fb-comments">` which is what my code above references.

Comment: So, could I just replace the code I am using for the above? And thank you for your help.

Comment: I've added the code you told me to add to the bottom of this page, and updated the CSS, but it's not displaying at all now? http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/aptitudetests_numerical.htm

Comment: You didn't replace `__YOUR_APP_ID_HERE__` with your app ID. =) I didn't want to include your app's ID in a public Gist, though maybe that's not actually bad since it's already public in your site's source.

Comment: This was all of the last code: <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
              <fb:comments href="assessmentday.co.uk" num_posts="5" width="605"></fb:comments> which bit do I add? Sorry :s

Comment: The code gets lost in the comment here. Why don't you paste it into a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or similar.

Alternately, just paste in the content of my Gist as is, replacing `__YOUR_APP_ID_HERE__` with your Facebook app ID. You can also adjust things like `data-num-posts` if you want.

Comment: Okay, this is what I had before - http://jsfiddle.net/pchuZ/ - edit this as to what I should have, and I'll upload it and test it out on my iPad and iPhone :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Edited: http://jsfiddle.net/pchuZ/1/ However, your jsfiddle doesn't include your FB app ID, which I remembered you had. You can get it by going to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ clicking "Get code" and selecting the app you want to use, then grabbing the `appId` from the code snippet. Replace `__YOUR_APP_ID_HERE__` with that and it should work.

Comment: I've clicked your FB link, "Get code" and there is no selection of which app I want to use, and no where where it says appId. Where are you seeing this, can you send me a screen shot please?

Comment: Okay I'm nearly there :) - I now have my AppID but still the FB comments plugin still appears half the size it should in both an iPad and iPhone. How can I get them to render to the full width of the container? :0 http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/aptitudetests_numerical.htm

Comment: It looks fine to me on an iPad: http://cl.ly/image/1D0e2Q1m2e19 On an iPhone it's indeed small: http://cl.ly/image/3F3n0o063g2J But that's because your site doesn't show a mobile layout using meta viewport, which the mobile Facebook Comments are meant for: https://www.google.com/search?q=meta+viewport So in this case, if you just always want to show the full-width comments, you could make everything simple and just use `data-mobile="false"` always. Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/pchuZ/2/

Comment: Ha you're a genuis :) thank you very much for all your help with this Aseem.